# My Button event button does not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am doing project in vb.Net

I set button in my .aspx file

```
<asp:Button ID="ExportBtn" runat="server" CssClass="button large blue"  Text="Export" OnClick="ExportBtn_Click" />
```

Code behind it, (i.e) in .aspx.vb

```
Protected Sub ExportBtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ExportBtn.Click
    rgList.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = True
    rgList.ExportSettings.FileName = "IyarkaiStockInHand"
    rgList.MasterTableView.AllowFilteringByColumn = False

    'rgList.MasterTableView.Columns(7).Visible = False
    'rgList.MasterTableView.Columns(5).Visible = False

    ''Dim BoundColumn As Telerik.Web.UI.GridBoundColumn = New Telerik.Web.UI.GridBoundColumn()
    ''rgList.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(BoundColumn)
    rgList.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel()
End Sub
```

My problem is, the button event does not fire when click.

Comment: Have you copied this button ?

Comment: Make sure the button is registered on the `".designer.cs"` file

Comment: if not, just make a new button, copy its event content and paste it into the new one

Comment: put EnableEventValidation <%@ Page Title=""   EnableEventValidation="false"  %>

Comment: I am not copied it from anywhere. It's already registered in .designer.vb file.

Comment: hi Denish Parvadia, <%@ Page Title="" EnableEventValidation="false" %>  . it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Handles ExportBtn.Click` as it is already specified in `aspx`.

```
Protected Sub ExportBtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
```

Or remove `OnClick="ExportBtn_Click"` from mark up.

```
<asp:Button ID="ExportBtn" runat="server" CssClass="button large blue"  Text="Export" />
```

Don't remove both.

Comment: Bro, did that. yet not any improvement

Comment: @MathavaRajan Have you checked in that event is really attached with button in button properties?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround than a solution but I have had similar problems in the past.  I put in an AddHandler method for the buttons in the Page_Load method.